# How do I write a generic extension method to convert a List to a HashSet using HashSet.AddRange()?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, hashset

HashSet does not have an AddRange method, so I want to write an extension method for it. This is what I have:

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

I have a base class, Media, and a derived class, Photo. This is the code that I want to work:

```
var photos = new List<Photo>();
var media = new HashSet<Media>();
media.AddRange(photos);
```

However, the compiler is telling me that it can't convert the `List<Photo>` to `IEnumerable<Media>` when I try to use `AddRange()`. I'm pretty sure this is because I have `IEnumerable<T>` in the extension method, but how do I write it so that the type is different than the type in `AddRange<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another generic-variance issue.  You will need to call the `Cast<Media>` extension method to convert the `IEnumerable<Photo>` to `IEnumerable<Media>` before it will be acceptable to your `AddRange` implementation's signature.

Alternatively, you can declare

```
AddRange<T, U>(ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<U>) where U : T
```

as a workaround to produce the correct variance in the signature.

Comment: When you say `Cast<Media>`, are you saying to write it myself or is it something that's included with the .NET Framework?

Comment: That's in the .NET framework in the System.Linq namespace as an extension method on IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I just found it. I was trying to use Cast<Media>(Blahblah) instead of Blahblah.Cast<Media>.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, `HashSet<T>` may not have an `AddRange` method, but it has a `UnionWith` method, which is semantically what you are looking for.  The difference in name reflects the fact that it filters out duplicates.  It also has a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as a parameter, if you just want to copy a collection into a `HashSet`.

In the general case, the above answer recommending to use a generic constraint ("`where T : U`") is correct.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that. Combined with Jeffrey's `Cast<Media>` answer, this means I can get rid of my extension method!

Comment: Just an additional note: the actual method is `Union`, not `UnionWith`, and it returns an IEnumerable<T>. I had to use the extension method after all because I needed to add to the HashSet.

Comment: There's an IEnumerable<T> extension method called Union that you can use to take the union of any two sequences, but if you've got a HashSet<T> already, it has a separate method, UnionWith, that will be more efficient, since it extends your existing set instead of allocating an entirely new one.

Comment: To clarify things, there are `HashSet.UnionWith()` and `Enumerable.Union()` methods and the latter is extension method.